# "process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app" when launching AdHoc app

Tags: ios, xcode

When I have Xcode run the AdHoc version of my app on my test iPhone, the app starts launching, but then crashes and gives me the following error:

```
process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app
```

Here are my Code Signing settings:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this crash? It doesn't crash like this when I run it in iOS simulator with the same settings.

Here is the console:

```
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Fetching NTP time from "time.apple.com" count:3 timeout:60.00
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063504.739296 wlan.A[4990] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063509.764068 wlan.A[4991] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063625.316954 wlan.A[4992] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063675.553649 wlan.A[4993] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063791.109139 wlan.A[4994] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063806.199158 wlan.A[4995] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 063891.584419 wlan.A[4996] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064017.215490 wlan.A[4997] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064052.343788 wlan.A[4998] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -69
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064117.568636 wlan.A[4999] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064172.755110 wlan.A[5000] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064177.756703 wlan.A[5001] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064182.780013 wlan.A[5002] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064263.134225 wlan.A[5003] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064288.260978 wlan.A[5004] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064293.269917 wlan.A[5005] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064298.271480 wlan.A[5006] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 064318.330708 wlan.A[5007] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -72
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 065166.676591 wlan.A[5008] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -70
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: 065181.752859 wlan.A[5009] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 50, fAverageRSSI -71
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Got NTP time 2014-09-08 17:52:32 +0000 ± 0.04 at 1578227637325 (delay 0.05, dispersion 0.01)
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: NTP succeeded with 431891552.62±0.04 at 1578227637325
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 09/08/2014 17:52:32±0.04 from "NTPLowConfidence"
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting system time to 09/08/2014 17:52:32 from NTP because time is unchanged
Sep  8 13:52:32 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in -0.00hrs. Need active time in 83.33hrs.
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Got NTP time 2014-09-08 17:52:32 +0000 ± 0.03 at 1578228967670 (delay 0.05, dispersion 0.01)
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: NTP succeeded with 431891552.62±0.03 at 1578227637325
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 09/08/2014 17:52:32±0.03 from "NTP"
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting system time to 09/08/2014 17:52:32 from NTP because time is unchanged
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 41.23hrs. Need active time in 124.56hrs.
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Got NTP time 2014-09-08 17:52:32 +0000 ± 0.11 at 1578233785172 (delay 0.20, dispersion 0.02)
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: NTP got responses from 3 servers total
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: NTP succeeded with 431891552.62±0.03 at 1578227637325
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 09/08/2014 17:52:32±0.03 from "NTP"
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting system time to 09/08/2014 17:52:32 from NTP because time is unchanged
Sep  8 13:52:33 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 41.23hrs. Need active time in 124.56hrs.
Sep  8 13:54:59 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received timezone "America/New_York" from "Location"
Sep  8 13:54:59 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Current mcc: '0' simulated:'0'.
Sep  8 13:54:59 Andrew-Ghobrials-iPhone timed[18] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Not setting time zone to America/New_York from Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I had to change the debug to development profiles.

Comment: You had to change the Distribution to development profile in the Debug Signing Identity - please don't fix up the correct naming, as it is crucial for others to understand the solution. Besides, this is what the other guy also stated out ;D